# Can I use transfer learning to retrain a Neural Network on different subsets of the data to solve memory problems?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I am trying to train a Neural Network on the [Amazon Reviews DataSet](https://www.kaggle.com/bittlingmayer/amazonreviews/data), so that I can teach it to classify correctly between Positive and Negative sentiment. The approach I am trying to use is to first use Google's Word2Vec model to vectorize each review, by sampling the vector from the model. Then, I feed them into a Convolutional Neural Network to train it.

I obtained Google's Pre-trained Word2Vec model from [here](http://mccormickml.com/2016/04/12/googles-pretrained-word2vec-model-in-python/), which gives me a Vector of length 300-dimensions, and by truncating each review to 80 words, I obtain a 80 x 300 Vector for each review.

The Convolutional Neural Network I train has the following structure:

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape    

- conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 1, 300, 128)       

- conv2d_2 (Conv2D)            (None, 1, 300, 64)        

- conv2d_3 (Conv2D)            (None, 1, 300, 32)        

- conv2d_4 (Conv2D)            (None, 1, 300, 16)        

- flatten_1 (Flatten)          (None, 4800)              

- dropout_1 (Dropout 0.5)      (None, 4800)              

- dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 256)               

- batch_normalization_1 (Batch (None, 256)               

- activation_1 (Relu)          (None, 256)               

- dropout_2 (Dropout 0.5)      (None, 256)               

- dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 1)
```

I use a large Network with big dropout and neurons to reduce overfitting on the Training data.

However, my main problem is that I am unable to train on most of the data because I can't load all of the data in memory, and since the Featurized vectors contain mostly high-precision decimals, they take up a lot of memory, and disk space if I serialize them.

Is it possible for me to use Transfer Learning to solve the problem of not training on enough data? The approach I plan on using is:

- Load a subset of the dataset that can fit into the memory
- Vectorize it using Google's Word2Vec model (This part takes around 5-10 minutes)
- Train the model for 50-100 epochs
- Load in a second subset of the dataset and repeat.

Is this a valid approach for training a large model? Because I am re-training the model on the same dataset, am I correct in assuming that I won't have to freeze any layers?

Also, is Stochastic Gradient Descent a good optimizer for this problem, since I will be training on a large amount of data?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of your proposed method, I think it would be more appropriate if you used a data generator.